# How to print a tensor's value inside tf.while_loop without returning it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, printing, while-loop, tensor

What I want is to print a tensor's value inside tf.while_loop body without returning the tensor but still using a computational graph. Below I have some simple examples to explain what I want to succeed and what I have done so far.

Method 1 (works):

TF supports an option to print tensors while evaluating a model by introducing tf.Print operation to the graph, but that requires for the tensor to be returned from the body :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1])

def body(x):
    a = tf.constant( np.array([2]) , dtype=tf.float32)
    x = a + x
    x = tf.Print(x,[x], summarize=100) <= print here (works)
    return x

def condition(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(x) < 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    result = tf.while_loop(cond=condition, body=body, loop_vars=[x])
    result_out = sess.run([result], feed_dict={ x : np.zeros(1)})
    print(result_out)
```

Out :

```
[2]
[4]
[6]
[8] 
[10]
[array([10.], dtype=float32)]
```

Method 2 (works):

TF supports an option to print tensors without creating a computational graph using Eager mode. Same example below :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

def body(x):
    a = tf.constant(np.array([2]), dtype=tf.int32)
    x = a + x
    print(x) <= print here (works)
    return x

def cond(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(x) < 10 # sum over an axis

x = tf.constant(0, shape=[1])

#result = tf.while_loop(cond=condition, body=body, loop_vars=(x,0))
result=tf.while_loop(cond, body, [x])
print(result)
```

Out :

```
tf.Tensor([2], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([6], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([8], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)

tf.Tensor([10], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([10], shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

Method 3 (failed):

What I want is to print the tensor using eager execution in a graph environment (like described : [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager)).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tfe = tf.contrib.eager

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [1])

def my_py_func(x):
  print(x)  # It's eager!

def body(x):
    a = tf.constant( np.array([2]) , dtype=tf.int32)
    x = a + x
    tfe.py_func(my_py_func, x, tf.int32) <= print here (does not work)
    return x

def condition(x):
    return tf.reduce_sum(x) < 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    result = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [x])
    result_out = sess.run([result], feed_dict={ x : np.zeros(1)} )
    print(result_out)
```

Out :

```
TypeError: Expected list for 'input' argument to 'EagerPyFunc' Op, not Tensor("while/add:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32).
```

Of course in this example I return tensor `x` from the body, but I want to print inside the loop !

Comment: Why is the first method not acceptable? If you do `x = tf.Print(x, [a], summarize=100)` you would be printing the value of tensor `a` without returning this tensor.

Comment: I thought that tf.Print is only for printing the tensors that are returned. Thank you very much it works. Can you post it as an answer for me accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first method, you can print the value of a tensor without returning it. For example:

```
x = tf.Print(x, [a])
```

In this case, [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) is an identity operation with the side effect of printing the value of tensor `a` when evaluating.